# Why are half of my local variables flagged as flakey, and the others are accepted?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2013

Either I'm experiencing an especially profound moment of denseness, or something very strange is going on here. My code compiles, but half of the vars into which I'm temporarily storing database reads are "normal" and the rest are grayed out where they are declared and marked as red where they are used by the IDE:

[image]

Why?

### UPDATE

I ran the R# inspection on the project, and the only thing it advised I change in that code was this:

```
while (sqlD8aReader != null && sqlD8aReader.Read())
```

...to this:

```
while (sqlD8aReader.Read())
```

Comment: Youre using R# right?

Comment: Looks like Resharper highlighting? I see this occasionally; usually it goes away after closing the file.

Comment: A side note: accessing database result set columns by indexes is a **terrible** idea.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't leave home without R#. I mean, I wouldn't want to code without R#.

Comment: @zerkms: Why? Can't they be expected to always be in the same location?

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon: there is a less error prone and a better maintainable solution: use column names.

Comment: Oh, I get your point. Have you got the syntax for that off the top of your head?

Comment: I found it:
int dept = (oleDbD8aReader["department"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(oleDbD8aReader["department"]));

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: as long as you don't change the query, the column order won't change.  But it's still a bad idea -- you are tying your code, not to the data, but the order the daya is returned.  If that was a stored procedure, the column sequence could be changed without your knowledge.  If you decided to put the sql into a constant somewhere else, it might be changed without your knowing it.  And what do you gain by using index? Nothing really.